# How to find process name from registry key and to kill the selected processes?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Im about to kill some process which can be selected dynamically from  the user end. I have coded to display the installed software list. But the thing is display  name is different from the service name.So,some of the applications cant get killed.When i try to get exe file names,it often throws me access denied error.

```
 string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
        {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (rk == null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            List<string> location = new List<string>();
                            string getname = sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString();

                            if (getname != null)
                            {
                                location.Add(sk.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString());
                                lstInstalled.Items.Add(new { Col1 = getname });
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { }

                    }
         }}
```

here is the  code to kill selected applications

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string cs = row["softwarename"].ToString().ToLower();

                string[] namelist = cs.Split(' ');

                var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process pc in allProcesses)
                {
                    try { 
                    if (cs.Any(pc.ProcessName.ToString().ToLower().Contains))
                    {
                    pc.Kill();
                    }
                        }
                        catch {
 }
                }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you got exe name? Process has MainModule which is a ProcessModule so it has FileName and ModuleName

Comment: Is this a CA in MSI script? Otherwise, please don't do this.

Comment: Installed Software and Process are two different things. Do you want to list the running processes? If you list installed Software what do you want to kill?

Comment: I'm in a need of preventing some software from being opened.(Chrome,notepad,msword etc) The thing is the set of those software should get selected dynamically as per user's choice. @Arif Eqbal

Comment: ok, so I guess you have two tasks in hand, first is to list the installed apps to the user and prevent the selected apps from starting. And your first problem it seems is that the list shows lot of unexpected installed software.

Comment: yeah that is alright i can filter it . I compare the words of software's name with current processing process list... I do have one issue . My code fails in a scenario in which process name and software name are different.For example , bandicam is a software name but it's process name is bdcam..

Comment: Don't write code, use AppLocker or Software Restriction Policies to control application launch.

Comment: Yeah tanveer you are right. But i have  a requirement as i described. Btw,I found the solution .Thanks